# TOC: center 'Part' and wrap subsubsection properly

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to center PART and wrap the subsubsection in one line in TOC, with proper indentation (matching with section or subsection or chapter). Please see the image. Attached is the sample code too. Thank you very much.

[image: Sample Current Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,bothside]{book}


\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{~\cftdotfill{5}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% to center part
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{\hfill}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{part}}

%wrap TOC contents
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}% <section>
  [1.5em]% <left>
  {\scriptsize}% <above-code>
  {}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {,\ \thecontentspage}% <filler-page-format>
  [\ - \ ]% <separator>
  [\\]% <end>


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}


\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subection 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation for `tocloft` says, in standard classes (such as `book`) `\cftpartaftersnum` has no effect.  Instead you can patch the generating command for this entry, `\l@part`, adding extra code to the instance `#1`, where the title is inserted, to add the filling from the right (and to remove a fixed space to the right).

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@part}{#1}{#1\hfill\hskip-\rightskip\mbox{}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Note the solutions given at [Center parts in toc with tocloft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67413/15925)
do not work when the page number of the part is suppressed.

For the subsubsection I think you must just choose one indentation amount.  I suggest making it so it fits under sections or indenting further to its own alignment.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}%
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{~\cftdotfill{5}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% to center part
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@part}{#1}{#1\hfill\hskip-\rightskip\mbox{}}{}{}
\makeatother
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{part}}

%wrap TOC contents
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents*{subsubsection}% <section>
  [3.8em]% <left>
  {\scriptsize}% <above-code>
  {}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {,\ \thecontentspage}% <filler-page-format>
  [\ - \ ]% <separator>
  [\\]% <end>

\begin{document}
\showoutput
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}


\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subection 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}


\end{document}
```