# How to center part entries in toc with memoir?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm typesetting a book with `memoir` class and in this book the parts have to be centred in the table of contents (TOC). Thanks to [Center parts in toc with tocloft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67413) I got this working as long as the part name isn't longer than one line. But if it is longer, the second line is not centred. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\partnumberline}[1]{\hfil\hspace\@tocrmarg Teil #1:~}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\large\normalfont}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\part{It works with one liners}
\chapter{Test}
\Blindtext
\section{Test124}
\Blindtext
\part{But it does not work with those: That is only a test nothing more, please do not read it}
\chapter{Test2}
\Blindtext \Blindtext \Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

What could I do to get all lines centred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to not use the memoir interface at all!

Instead go straight to the source and recode it. Here I have removed all the code that normally makes space for the page number and the left indentation etc.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\partnumberline}[1]{Teil #1:~}
\renewcommand*{\l@part}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \cftpartbreak
    \begingroup
      {
        \setlength{\memRTLleftskip}{0pt}
        \setlength{\memRTLrightskip}{0pt}
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \centering
        \cftpartfont #1
        \par
      }
      \nobreak
        \global\@nobreaktrue
        \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\large\normalfont}
```