# Center the "part name" in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft, parts

I want to change in the table of contents the look of the `parts`. I reproduced on Word what I want :

[image]

I've looked into the site if the question was already answered but I didn't found what I want.

All I want is to center the part name in the TOC and also get rid of the page number. I am using the `book` class and I don't want to use other document classes.

Thank you.

EDIT. Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\chapter{A first chapter}
\chapter{A second one}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{A third one}
\chapter{The last one}
\end{document}
```

Here is my preambule with `titlesec` :

```
\documentclass{book}

%Redifining paragraph spacing and thus spacing in the TOC
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{ 0.4\baselineskip}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{9pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{5pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{9pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{2pt plus 2pt minus  2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{9pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{2pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% Here the code of Christian Hupfer
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\chapter{A first chapter}
\chapter{A second one}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{A third one}
\chapter{The last one}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The usual way is to provide a starter document

Comment: I think your question has been answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67413/center-parts-in-toc-with-tocloft).

Comment: I must haven't write the right words in my research.

Comment: The duplicate is only for the koma classes, not book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `part` number should be centered as well, I choose to use a patch for the `\addcontentsline` within `\@part` -- note this is only working of the `\secnumdepth` is greater than `-1`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\bfseries\protect\centering\thepart\hspace{1em}#1\par}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{How to provide a MWE}

\chapter{Foo}


\part{How not to be seen}

\chapter{Arthur Gumby}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, so rapid and precise, thanks a lot, exactly what I want !

Comment: Hummm... it works with MWEs but when I use the package `titlesec` it doesn't work anymore. To be precise I use the `titlesec` package for changing vertical spaces in the TOC because I redefined the `parskip`. I put the code in my last edition of my initial message.

Comment: @M.LTA: That wasn't in your question above. `titlesec` is a very strange package, in my point of view

Comment: No that wasn't my question above ... consider it a new question if you want ^^ Still I didn't realized that this package would interact.

Answer (score 1):

To get the part number centered, I had to use the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartleader{\hfill}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\part{Parte the First}

\section{Introduction}
\section{Next Section}

\part{Parte the Second}

\section{Introduction}
\section{Next Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is without `tocloft` and without centering of the part number.  I also needed to introduce `\cpart` that uses the optional argument of `\part` to achieve toc centering.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\newcommand\cpart[1]{\part[\hfill#1\hfill]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\cpart{Parte the First}

\section{Introduction}
\section{Next Section}

\cpart{Parte the Second}

\section{Introduction}
\section{Next Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, you didn't answer my precise question, but still I like that you provided me with different style of table of contents ! Thank you !